# Should I use constant current or constant voltage drivers for driving my PWM 24V DC Fans?

Tags: arduino, pwm, fan, 24v

Hi everyone thanks for stopping by to lend your thoughts.

I need to run 2 circuits separately and control via Arduino uno PWM.

One circuit is 2x Noctua NF-A14 industrialPPC-24V-3000 Q100 IP67 with 4pin PWM connection. The spec sheet says:
Max. input power 7,92 W 
Max. input current 0,33 A
Operating voltage 24 V 
Voltage PWM Signal 5 V

The second circuit is 3x Noctua NF-F12 industrialPPC-2000 IP67 with 4pin PWM
Its spec sheet says:
Max. input power 1,2 W
Max. input current 0,1 A
Operating voltage 12 V

Do I need to use constant current or constant voltage drivers for these circuits and what kind of resistors and other things might I also need to pull this off? I am leaning towards using Meanwell LED drivers for this task as the only other electronics I'm somewhat familiar with is those.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The industrialPPC fans are great.  When you're looking for drivers, you should take into account the speed(s) you want to run at.  Mine only run at full blast for about 2 seconds right when my computer turns on, but they are LOUD at full blast and because of the high power/static pressure, you may well want to run them much lower than that for most purposes.  Have you given them a test run?

Answer (score 1):

Fans require constant voltage, so you need two separate rails, one at 24V and one at 12V. Your power supply/supplies must be able to deliver to the specs (0.66A (=2x0.33A) and 0.3A (3x0.1A) respectively, of course you want to design conservatively so pick a power supply with ample headroom, e.g. 24V 1A and 12V 0.5A).

For the PWM control the Uno has all you need, just feed the PWM signal from the Arduino to the respective PWM pin on each fan.

Comment: If the 'max' input says 0.33 and I deliver .5 isn't that bad?

Comment: Would the Meanwell IRM-05-12 be a good choice for the 3x 12V fans?
http://www.meanwellusa.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=IRM-05

Comment: Is the Meanwell APV-16-24 the perfect fit for the 2x NF-A14?
http://www.meanwellusa.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=APV-16

Comment: Current doesn't have to be "matched" - a power supply only outputs as much current as the load (fans in your case) needs. The 0.5A supply will output 0.33A if that's what the fans consume. Having both the voltage and current "fit perfectly" to the load is good, but it's better to have a supply that is a bit overprovisioned on current, to cater for inrush current when starting, capability for future expansion (e.g. adding more fans) or whatnot.